# Getting image download links from owncloud server

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, owncloud

there is not much information out there for the newbies to owncloud.. not even here in Stack Overflow, a little background on what im trying to achieve is:

-Already managed to sync my project to the owncloud library via gradlle.
- The provided examples are not of much help for me you will see why.

I use this library https://github.com/bumptech/glide to stream images URLs to some imageviews in my app, as i was on a web server I had no problem but now that I moved to owncloud, I can do the same if i provide my app with the "download link" from the stored images.

That said, what I need is to some how be able to select the owncloud stored images(access the shared folder and download) by name and or read the download link from where ever is stored..

here is the use the glide library on my project

```
 String url = null;
        if (plato.getFoto_movil().equals("churrasco.jpg"))
        {
            url = "http://192.168.0.20/owncloud/index.php/s/EqX7LxLpUeBCzF4/download";
        }

        if (plato.getFoto_movil().equals("pizza.jpg"))
        {
            url = "http://192.168.0.20/owncloud/index.php/s/VGQJh6ii36PLGsN/download";
    }


        if (plato.getFoto_movil().equals("torta_chocolate.jpg"))
        {
            url = "http://192.168.0.20/owncloud/index.php/s/K0TaHRMPuMrs0Fx/download";
        }


        Glide.with(mContext).load(url).into(imageView);
```

which is sad because I had to manually get those URLs from my browser and it does not work with the newly added images from any othere device, so I need to be able to get any new image and show it too.

I have the library installed 100% and implemented but

```
      private void startDownload(String filePath, File targetDirectory) {
                DownloadRemoteFileOperation downloadOperation = new DownloadRemoteFileOperation(filePath, targetDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                downloadOperation.addDatatransferProgressListener((OnDatatransferProgressListener) mContext);
                downloadOperation.execute( mClient, (OnRemoteOperationListener) mContext, mHandler);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransferProgress(long l, long l1, long l2, String s) {
                mHandler.post( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // do your UI updates about progress here
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onRemoteOperationFinish(RemoteOperation remoteOperation, RemoteOperationResult remoteOperationResult) {
                if (remoteOperation instanceof DownloadRemoteFileOperation) {
                    if (remoteOperationResult.isSuccess()) {
                    }
                }
            }


got those and 

got also this two
            mClient = OwnCloudClientFactory.createOwnCloudClient(serverUri,mContext,true);
            mClient.setCredentials(OwnCloudCredentialsFactory.newBasicCredentials(username,password));
```

then I call the method

```
startDownload(plato.getFoto_movil(),downloadfolder);
```

the app crashes here when I call the startdowonload method
with the error      java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eidotab.eidotab.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.owncloud.android.lib.common.network.OnDatatransferProgressListener

another relevant information is that im implementing the ownclod methods to 
the viewholder of a recyclerview

```
public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnRemoteOperationListener, OnDatatransferProgressListener
```

but I could change to the main activity if needed, probably make it work from there but even if it does have success, don´t know where or how to get the download links, like I said, I need the download link from every image stored in the server..

is this possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: `MainActivity cannot be cast `.  So implement that interface there

Comment: yes that I said.. i can implement the methods there, but what im worried is about how to get the links.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the implementation of the owncloud library to the main activity as suggested (and was the logical move) and everything went smooth.. worked at first try, I knew it was going to, the thing is that I didnt want to store the images on the device memory, I want to capture the download links which was my main concern but for now it is working since im streaming the images directly from the local sd to the imageview and that should give me some more time to investigate further in the matter whats the thing with the URLS...

Thanks cricket for your comments